# how do i create this query for mongodb(cmd) "Update Doctors Set Talent=Talent.Replace(" ","&").ToLower()"

Tags: sql, mongodb

I have a lot of data, so I write with windows cmd, my queries.

I'm using mssql this way to

```
Update Doctors Set Talent=Talent.Replace(" ","&").ToLower()
```

How can I create for mongodb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MongoDB Version is at least 4.2 you can use updateMany with a one-stage aggregation pipeline if your `Talent` property is a single string value:

```
db.Doctors.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      Talent: {
        $toLower: { // Make it lowercase
          $substr: [ // Remove the initial '&' that got added while putting it back together
            {
              $reduce: {
                input: { $split: ['$Talent', ' ']}, // Take it apart
                initialValue: '',
                in: { $concat: [ '$$value', '&', '$$this']} // Put it back together with '&' in place of ' '
              }
            }, 
            1,
            -1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

If your `Talent` property is an array of strings you also need to map it:

```
db.Doctors.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      Talent: {
        $map: {
          as: 'singleTalent', 
          input: '$Talent',
          in: {
            $toLower: { 
              $substr: [ 
                {
                  $reduce: {
                    input: { $split: [ "$$singleTalent", ' ']}, 
                    initialValue: '',
                    in: { $concat: [ '$$value', '&', '$$this']} 
                  }
                }, 
                1,
                -1
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for answer , it was really useful
So what method should I apply if the Talent field is of the array type?

Comment: If the Talent field is already an array and there are **no** spaces in the strings that you want to get rid of you can just skip the `$split` like `input: '$Talent'`

Comment: Did you replace `{ $split: ['$Talent', ' ']}` with `$Talent` and what is the error you're getting?

Comment: Im using like that 
db.Doctors.updateMany(
  {},
  [{
    $set: {
      Talent: {
        $toLower: { 
          $substr: [ 
            {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$Talent", 
                initialValue: '',
                in: { $concat: [ '$$value', '-', '$$this']} 
              }
            }, 
            1,
            -1
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Result;

Categories:"construction building contractors-real estate developers-real estate a..."

it happend like that

Comment: To clarify: you have an array of talents and you want to have the spaces in each **individual** talent changed to some other symbol and you also want to keep the Talent field as an array?

Comment: Old:
Talent:["Bla Bla","bla "bla vla"]
I want
Talent:["bla-bla","bla-bla"]

Comment: @Totales i changed my answer to also include what to do for an array of strings